# Converting an address to lattitude and longitude

Tags: html, geolocation, geocoding

I am trying to convert an address to latitude and longitude but the values are not displaying. 
I even want to store the result in database, but I am not able to get lat/long in first place. I would like to know where I have gone wrong.

Below is the code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Theater</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&language=en" ></script>
    <script>
    // Called when page is loaded
    function Init( )
    {
    var address = Document.getElementById("address");
    var city = Document.getElementById("city");
    var state = Document.getElementById("state");
    var zip = Document.getElementById("zip");
    var country = Document.getElementById("country");
        // make google call to convert address to lat/lng coordinate
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address+city+state+zip+country}, ShowLatLng );
    }

    // This function is the called when Google geocode() returns the result of geocoding an address
    function ShowLatLng( results, status )
    {
        if ( status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK )
        {
            document.getElementById( 'latlng' ).innerHTML = results[0].geometry.location;
        }
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table><tr>
<td> Address &emsp; </td>
<td><input type="text" name="address" id="address"> </td>   </tr>
<tr><td> City</td><td><input type="text" name="city" id="city"></td>
<td>State </td><td><input type="text" name="state" id="state"></td></tr>
<tr><td>zip</td><td><input type="text" name="zip" id="zip"></td>
<td>Country</td><td><input type="text" name="country" id="country"></td>
</tr></table>
<input type="button" onclick="Init()" value="Determine Lat/Lon">
<label id="latlng"></label>
```

Comment: What error messages are you seeing in the browser's JavaScript console? There's one glaring error - `Documet`

Comment: No error. Its just not displaying. @Pekka 웃

Comment: There's *got* to be an error at `var address = Documet.getElementById("address");` because of the typo `Documet`. Are you sure you are looking in the error console?

Comment: @Shraddha : Did you get answer of this question?

Comment: No, I want it to fetch the address which we enter and convert it to latitude and longitude @Nana Partykar

Comment: I Can Provide You Code (Which Is Not In Javascript). If You Say YES.

Comment: Yes!  I will try to work with that instead. Thanks a lot @ Nana Partykar

Answer (score 0):

You said you're not seeing any JS errors in your console, so my best guess is your address isn't matching.

I have two ideas on the issue.

First, maybe the address is incorrectly formatted. Sometimes geocoding APIs can't match the address because there are abbreviations, missing words (like "street" or "road", etc), because the numbers have dashes or other breaks, or other punctuation and spelling possibilities. It's very useful to do address [standardization](https://smartystreets.com/articles/address-standardization) — making an address uniform — and [validation](https://smartystreets.com/articles/what-is-address-validation) — checking an address against a database — to get the formatting correct. I see that you're using the Google Maps API and Google does really well with search terms, but that isn't to say they are perfect at address standardization and they don't do address validation.

Second, your code here:

```
geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address+city+state+zip+country}, ShowLatLng );
```

probably doesn't work correctly. If:

```
address = "123 My House Road";
city = "My City";
state = "AA";
zip = "12345";
country = "USA";
```

then `address+city+state+zip+country` results in `123 My House RoadMy CityAA12345USA`. Notice that there are no spaces between the parts of the address. That is basically the same problem as I mentioned above: the address isn't matching — it isn't being found.

(Full disclosure: I worked for SmartyStreets, an address verification company.)